# Push under same change id after merge conflict

Tags: git, gerrit

I am using `git` and `gerrit` for code reviews. After pushing a change with a unique `change id`, there was a merge conflict issue on `gerrit` dashboard. So I pulled code again, resolved the merge conflict and then decided to amend the changes under the same change id.

But `git` won't allow this. `Amend` cannot be done if there is a `merge conflict`. You have to do a separate commit.

Is there any way to push my updated code under the same `change id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing "Change-Id" (Gerrit) with "Commit-Id" (Git). When you resolved the conflict and amended the original commit, a new commit was generated with (of course) a new Commit-Id. You can (actually, you need) keep the same Change-Id in the last line of the commit message, like for example:

Change-Id: Id65100bb3841c73bb9dd2d2d6a69c77a5936681a

When you push this commit to Gerrit, it will use this line to know that this commit is an amend of the original one and it will add it to the original change as a new patchset.

See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#push_replace).

Comment: i know commit id and change ids are different, its just that i got used to bitbucket and github, but gerrit is required for the current env i m working with, so it was a bit of tension to amend all the time :). Thanks for the link, it helped a lot.

Comment: I understand the "tension" Gerrit works a little bit different but you'll feel very comfort with it as soon as you get used.

Comment: Using the `Change-Id` displayed in the Gerrit UI is the key to solving this - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> then decided to amend the changes under the same change id

When you amend a commit in Git, either via `git commit --amend`, through Gerritt, or some other tool, you *create* a new commit.  The old commit has been rewritten and is no longer a part of your branch.

So, even if you amended the previous commit after resolving the merge conflict, there would still be a new commit present.

Answer (score 0):

No. When you try to amend the commit a new commit is recorded with new hash by replacing the preceding commit. If you want to combine them together and make it a one commit you may use squashing or you can use soft reset 2 commits and create a new commit out of those 2 by risking conflict with the remote.